# Receive call if application is not running (Viber like calling feature)

Tags: sip, voip, skype, whatsapp, viber

I need to implement the VoIP calling feature just like Whatsapp/Viber/Skype. After login, If I quit the application. I can still receive the Audio/Video calls from my friends/Contacts.

I am using the `PortSIP` SDK for my VoIP implementations.

Please suggest any way of getting this thing done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pushkit type VOIP push notification to achieve this.

Even if the app is force stopped it'll get launched on the arrival of Pushkit VOIP pushnotifcation.

Here are some of it advantages

- The device is woken only when VoIP pushes occur, saving energy.
  Unlike standard push notifications, which the user must respond to before your app can perform an action, VoIP pushes go straight to your app for processing.
- VoIP pushes are considered high-priority notifications and are delivered without delay.
- VoIP pushes can include more data than what is provided with standard push notifications.
- Your app is automatically relaunched if it’s not running when a VoIP push is received.
- Your app is given runtime to process a push, even if your app is operating in the background.
- This type of notification can also carry upto 4096 bytes

Here are the references[Ref1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html),[Ref2](https://zeropush.com/guide/guide-to-pushkit-and-voip)